# Undo a projection in OSMnx

Tags: geopandas, osmnx

In OSMnx sosme operations, eg graph simplification, only work once the graph is properly projected, while some work correctly in lat/long. I would like to do soomething like:

1. project graph
2. operate on projected graph (eg simplify)
3. "unproject"  result
4. operate on result in original coordinates

How do I do the unproject step?

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimal reproducible code example of what you've got so far?

Comment: Without further details, the short answer is this: you project your graph from projection *a* to projection *b*, then re-project it from *b* to *a*.

Comment: @gboeing for example I followed the consolidate_intersections examples to simplify a road network, and I want to plot it with plot_graph_folium, but the x and y are changed. How can I set x and y with lat and long values?